# RSS viewer in SharePoint strange

Tags: sharepoint, rss

I am getting into strange situation regarding the RSS viewer on SharePoint

I have two environments of SharePoint (production & testing)

I was showing a specific RSS news (ABC) on both of them , and it was working after setting the proxies and other stuff.

Suddenly (may be due to some changes done on the production without testing), the RSS viewer on the production is not showing the RSS news it is showing protocol error, while it is still working fine on the testing environment.

Now the strange part is if I change the RSS of the one our management wants and put BBC or CNN news these works well on both the production and the test environment.

But the one we want it to work (which was working fine on both) do not work on the production and works fine on testing.

Any suggestions of how can I figure it out?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a network problem.  If the logs don't show anything more helpful for the protocol error I would try wireshark and see if you can see anything different bettween test and production.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the error you're getting? And, can your firewall be not well configured and the abc news be rejected?